# bootstrap Carousel 100% width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tried many things but just couldnt get it right i want the carousel to strech to screen size without white space on left and right side of the screen .Yes in there may similar posts and i have tried many a things but its not working and please explain why this is happenning

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cs34g/2/)

### HTML

```
                           <div class="col-lg-12  col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >

                                  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                          <!-- Indicators -->
                                          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                          </ol>

                                          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                                            <div class="item active">
                                              <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700/CC1111/FFF" alt="First Slide">
                                              <div class="carousel-caption">
                                              First Slide
                                              </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="item">
                                             <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700/449955/FFF" alt="Second Slide">
                                              <div class="carousel-caption">
                                               Second Slide
                                              </div>
                                            </div>

                                                <div class="item">
                                             <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700/" alt="Third Slide">
                                              <div class="carousel-caption">
                                               Third Slide
                                              </div>
                                            </div>

                                          </div>

                                          <!-- Controls -->
                                          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                          </a>
                                          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                          </a>
                                </div>





                           </div>

                    </div>


        </div>
```

### CSS

```
#Container_Carousel{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;

}
.item img{
     width:100%; 


}
body{
      margin:0;
    padding:0;

}
html,body{height:100%;}
.carousel,.item,.active{height:100%;}
.carousel-inner{height:100%;}
```

Comment: You mean like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cs34g/3/)?

Comment: yes exactly like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to your columns div

```
 <div class="no-padding col-lg-12  col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >

                              <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                                      <!-- Indicators -->
                                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                      </ol>

                                      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                                        <div class="item active">
                                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700/CC1111/FFF" alt="First Slide">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                                          First Slide
                                          </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="item">
                                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700/449955/FFF" alt="Second Slide">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                                           Second Slide
                                          </div>
                                        </div>

                                            <div class="item">
                                         <img src="http://placehold.it/1024x700/" alt="Third Slide">
                                          <div class="carousel-caption">
                                           Third Slide
                                          </div>
                                        </div>

                                      </div>

                                      <!-- Controls -->
                                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                                      </a>
                                      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                                      </a>
                            </div>





                       </div>

                </div>


    </div>
```

And then add this class to your css

```
 .no-padding {
   padding: 0;
 }
```

I have added a class because I do not want you to remove padding from the default column classes as you might need padding for some other structure. I have updated the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cs34g/13/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-lg-12  col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
```

is adding the padding.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need so much CSS.

### HTML

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="rows">
        <div class="carousel-contaier col-xs-12">
            <!-- your carousel here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#carousel .carousel-container {
    padding: 0;
}
```

And since Bootstrap 3 is mobile-first, you don't need to use grid classes for all viewport. You only need `col-xs-12`, [according to docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater **than or equal to the breakpoint sizes**, and **override grid classes targeted at smaller devices**. Therefore, applying any `.col-md-` class to an element **will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices** if a `.col-lg-` class is not present.

This also would make the code much cleaner.

Here is the demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuplizian/EG7v9/).